# Power BI report builder multiple selection in query

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am trying to figure out how to display results based on multi selection of the user.

[image]

So top drop down has a list of countries that a user can select from. This is how I am trying to get the list but the expression only wants to pick the first one.  How do I go about it selecting all selected values.

It works fine for one selection but not for multi selections

[image]

---

This is how I updated it with based on comment. But getting an error

### The FilterValue expression for the dataset 'XXX' contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

The definition of the report '' is invalid.

[image]

----------Update two----------------
So removing the extra ( helped and the report is rendering but the multiple selection is not responding in the report itself.  You can see, I have Country of Interest: United Kingdom, United States... But nothing displays on the report.

Its a drop down list but as the user starts selecting, they start showing up in a comma separated list.

[image]

Here is how the query is built

[image]

Comment: =join(Parameters!CountryNames.Value,",")) is what you are looking for if you want to display all the selections as a comma separated value.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, please check the attached screenshot in the post. I am getting the following error.  The FilterValue expression for the dataset 'xxx' contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected. 
 I am using odbc connection if that affects any of this.

Comment: you have an extra ) at the end, it should be =join(Parameters!CountryNames.Value,","). good example here https://www.sqlshack.com/using-multi-value-parameters-in-ssrs/

Comment: If none of the above helps, you will probably need to share the dataset query, at least the WHERE clause assuming that is how you are trying to implement the parameter

Comment: Thanks @Jon and Alan, I just updated the post under update 2. I am not seeing the results when there is more than 1 selection. There is no error but report is empty.

Comment: I think I figured it out, my connection is happening with ODBC and @param wasnt working.  I followed the example on this link and that worked out. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/creating-multi-value-parameter-through-ole-db-data-source